# How can I redirect just a single blogger.com page to an external URL?

Tags: html, url, redirect, blogs, blogger

I have a blogger.com blog that covers a variety of topics, including PC troubleshooting tips. I've decided to start a dedicated PC troubleshooting blog, using a different blogging service. I want to move some of those PC troublehshooting posts from the old blog to the new blog. I want people who end up at the old posts via search engines to be automatically redirected to the posts on the new blog.

- I know I can easily redirect the *entire* blog to an external blog, but I don't want that. I want to preserve the old blog, but just relocate some of its posts to the new one.
- I know I can redirect individual blogger.com pages to other pages within the same blog, but I don't want that either. I want to redirect to an external URL.

I can add html code to blog posts in blogger, but I think it only accepts code that goes into the {body} section. Perhaps my problem boils down to two questions:

- is there a way to edit the {head} section of a blog post without doing it for the entire blog?
- is there a way to do an automatic redirect using code that you put in the {body} section?

Comment: If the only thing you can edit is html then.. no way. Can you add javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wouldn't be a 301 redirect, but you could put this code inside your body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://myblog.blogger.com/mypost";
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Once I switched the tab on blogger from "compose" to "html", I could paste this code in, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use pages gadget for a proper search engine friendly 301 redirect. Go to layout > click pages gadget (or add it if you are not already using it) and edit it to simple add external page to your menu. The only caveat is that it will become a part of the menu and will not be a hidden redirect which you can only manually post in links.