# Looking for a way to redirect a blogger post to an external url

Tags: blogger, redirect

I'm looking for someone to help me interpret a question and answer posted that I followed on this site.  Here's a link to the original question:

[How can I redirect just a single blogger.com page to an external URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276425/how-can-i-redirect-just-a-single-blogger-com-page-to-an-external-url)

I'm having trouble understanding the application of the answer.  I can get into the html code section of the post editor, but I'm confused from here.

Heres the code I'm trying to insert into Blogger

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://myblog.blogger.com/mypost";
</script>
```

Where should I put my external site redirect?  Is that all I have to modify in this code?

I'm trying to have a blog post title link to an external source

I'm grateful in advance, 
Michael

Comment: Replace this link `http://myblog.blogger.com/mypost` to your own (External Link)

Comment: How can I have this only redirect once a post is clicked? If I put this in a post any time my main blog page is loaded it attempts the redirect. I would like this to only happen once a specific post is clicked

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1** Got to **Blogger** Post in Edit Mode

**Step 2** Add Javascript redirect code in post

```
<script>

window.location = "http://www.example.com/your-new-url-to-redirect-when-this-post-loads";

</script>
```

**[Complete Tutorial](http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-redirect-single-blogger-post-to-external-url/)**

Answer (score 0):

window.location = "http://myblog.blogger.com/mypost";

instead of http://myblog.blogger.com/mypost put your URL and it automatically redirects you to the other URL so i guess u should keep an Onclick even before running the java script